# How to combine two multidimensional arrays with showing duplicate keys or if duplicate, must add the values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got main array keys a1 and a2.

```
$array1 = array(a1=>array(200,300,300), a2=>array(100,600,200));
$array2 = array(a1=>array('gen','gen2','gen'), a2=>array('gen2','gen3','gen3'));
```

I want my output to be

```
'a1'=>array(
    'gen'=>200
    'gen2'=>300
    'gen'=>300
 ),
'a2'=>array(
    'gen2'=>100
    'gen3' =>600
    'gen3' =>200
)
```

or

```
'a1'=>array(
    'gen'=>500
    'gen2'=>300
)
'a2'=>array(
    'gen2'=>100
    'gen3'=>800
)
```

I have tried this code but not enough, It doesn''t show the duplicate or it's better if it shows the sum of of the value ofduplicate keys

```
<?php
$array1 = array(a1=>array(200,300,300), a2=>array(100,600,200));
$array2 = array(a1=>array('gen','gen2','gen'), a2=>array('gen2','gen3','gen3'));
$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = array_combine($array2[$k], $v);
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Thanks you very much for your help

Comment: you can't have duplicate keys, so it will have to be the latter (a sum)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(
    'a1' => array(200,300,300),
    'a2' => array(100,600,200));
$array2 = array(
    'a1' => array('gen','gen2','gen'),
    'a2' => array('gen2','gen3','gen3'));
$result = array('a1' => array(), 'a2' => array());
foreach($array2 as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2){
        if (array_key_exists($v2, $result[$k])){
            $result[$k][$v2] += $array1[$k][$k2];
        } else {
            $result[$k][$v2] = $array1[$k][$k2];
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a1] => Array
        (
            [gen] => 500
            [gen2] => 300
        )
    [a2] => Array
        (
            [gen2] => 100
            [gen3] => 800
        )
)
```

Comment: You're welcome. One way you can earn points is by accepting answers. It's just a matter of clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. Cheers!

Comment: I want it too but I'm just new here, not enough reputation to vote up. :-(

Comment: @jeffMendoza - You don't need reputation to accept answers. There should be a check mark below the arrows for accepting. The arrows are for voting (and you need reputation for that), and the check marks are for accepting.